# Intercept local requests to a remote server with Node.js

Tags: node.js

Using NodeJS, is it possible to listen to calls **from** `localhost:3000` **to** `my.site.com/resources/*` and serve those files locally instead ?

**Context:** my Angular app relies on resources from a CDN. Sometimes when the CDN is down, I want to serve these files locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to check if angular object is correctly loaded , if not you generate a new  tag a local link instead of CDN

```
<script src="//cdn_link/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (typeof angular != 'undefined') || document.write('<script src="local_link/angular.min.js")<\/script>')
</script>
```

For angular2 you can check for ng object instead of angular

Comment: Smart ! Thanks :) I wouldn't have thought of that solution :)